# Why is the whitespace to the left and right of a centered and hyperlinked image clickable?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Fiddle with code: https://jsfiddle.net/gk95e47p/

Html:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <p>text<br>more text</p>
  <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1632846/pexels-photo-1632846.jpeg">
  </a>
  <p>even more text<br>still more text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

When the above "code" is loaded, the whitespace around the image is clickable (hover your mouse). That is, the region between the left/right margins to the image is are a part of the link which the image encapsulates.

**How can I make this whitespace not clickable?**

Possibilities:

- there is a different way to center the image?
- there is a different way to make the image a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"whitespace"* is clickable because you made the `img` element a block level element.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements):

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

This causes the anchor to wrap the image plus the left and right margins.

To prevent the `img` from stretching to full width available (and by association the anchor element), you can apply your width styles to the anchor element or give the image its own container and center the content. You can do this with `text-align: center;` or `justify-content: center;` while changing the containers display value to flex (`display: flex;`).

As markup becomes more complex or automated (i.e. a CMS), you'll likely have to use the container solution.

#### Anchor Solution

```css
.center-img-link {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.center-img-link--100 {
  width: 100px;
}

.center-img-link img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>text<br>more text</p>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" class="center-img-link center-img-link--100">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1632846/pexels-photo-1632846.jpeg">
</a>
<p>even more text<br>still more text</p>
```

#### Text Alignment Solution

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>text<br>more text</p>
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1632846/pexels-photo-1632846.jpeg">
  </a>
</div>
<p>even more text<br>still more text</p>
```

#### Flexbox Solution

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex-h-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<p>text<br>more text</p>
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1632846/pexels-photo-1632846.jpeg">
  </a>
</div>
<p>even more text<br>still more text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `a` tag is the actual "clickable" thing in your HTML, so when you put margins into it, you are just making the `a` container bigger, so you should just put the margins to the `a` tag.

Like:

```
a {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

image
 {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

By the way, consider using CSS classes

Comment: Something is incomplete here. I believe you meant `image` to be `.image`. I'm also assuming that `.image` should be applied to `a`, i.e. `<a class="image">`. If so, this does not resize the image as in the OPs example, http://jsfiddle.net/ra9g8w1n/

Comment: By `image` I meant `image` because OP's using styles applied directly to tags, not to classes. Also, I recommended to use classes.

Answer (score 0):

That's all related to `display: block;`, and here it's the update, I just use the `div` to be full width and use `text-align: center;` to make it in centered

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

<html>
  <body>
  <p>text<br>more text</p>
  <div>
    <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1632846/pexels-photo-1632846.jpeg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <p>even more text<br>still more text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Because display block that makes it full width automatically like `<h1>`, or add `display: inline-block;` so you need to use it on div if you want not directly on image